# Orden en la ejecución de una expresión aritmética

Tags: c

Estoy intentando comprender el orden de ejecución de esta expresión:

```
x = (a - b++) * (--b - d) * b++ / (b - d);
```

Alguien me lo puede explicar porque no lo acabo de entender.

A mi lo que se me ocurre es:

Primero los paréntesis:

```
op1 = (a - b)
b++
--b
op2 = (b - d)
op3 = (b - d)
x = op1 * op2 * b / op3
b++
```

Pero no me sale bien:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float x = 0, a = 20, b = 10, d = 4;
    x = (a - b++) * (--b - d) * b++ / (b - d);
    printf("x = %g, b = %g\n", x, b);

    x = 0, a = 20, b = 10, d = 4;
    x = a - b;
    b++;
    --b;
    x*= (b - d) * b / (b - d);
    b++;
    printf("x = %g, b = %g\n", x, b);

}
```

x = 85.7143, b = 11
x = 100, b = 11

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 0):

Una tabla de precedencia de operadores la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Operadores_de_C_y_C%2B%2B).

Ahora, el ejemplo que tienes es engañoso porque el estándar de C **no determina el órden de evaluación de los operandos involucrados en una operación**.

Entonces, no hay regla que garantice que `(a - b++)` se ejecutará antes que `(--b - d)` o que `b++`. El órden dependerá del ambiente con el que compiles/ejecutes tu código.

Debido a que las tres operaciones modifican el valor de `b` la sugerencia será separar la operación mostrada para garantizar el órden de ejecución.